# Google Charts no longer display in IE11 from July 9th 2020

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, internet-explorer-11

We have used Google Charts in our website for several years without issue across all major browsers. This morning (July 9th 2020) all IE11 browsers now error when executing the chart library load code as shown below:

```
function loadGoogle() {
  // define callback in load statement
  try {
    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart","timeline"],'callback': loadcomplete});
  } catch(err) {
      cdpAlert("Google Charts Could not be loaded. Please check your internet connection. Error: " + err);
  }
}
```

The error is: 'object doesn't support object or method assign'.

[View Google Chart Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46PVl.png)

I have checked Google's own Chart Gallery and that also fails to display charts in IE11:

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?hl=es-419

The Singapore metro dashboard which is a Google featured site also fails to show charts in IE11:

http://failrailsg.appspot.com/overview.html

I can see no discussion about this on the web and no mention on the Google Charts website of any removal of support for IE11.

Has anyone encountered this issue or know anything about IE11 support being removed for Google Charts.

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2841

Comment: The polyfill.io script line fixed the problem for me. Thank you Andreas.

Comment: @Andreas I suggest you to put that as an answer so that Mike can mark it as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @YuZhou I don't think that a work-around for a bug in an issue tracker is really an answer... Feel free to add it as an answer. Or Mike can add it himself.

Comment: Since Andreas provided the work around and I'm a new contributor (although a long term viewer) I'll go with Andreas view and not add as an answer. Priceless as a workaround though when alll of our charts stopped working!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know until when it will continue to work, but checking the Google Charts website and realize that still working in Internet Explorer, check the references and it uses: https://www.gstatic.com/charts/48.1/loader.js not the normal one https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js